# Issues with Wake On Lan on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: boot, networking, ethernet, lan, wakeonlan

Recently i've been having a lot of issues trying to enable wake on lan on my server and i'm out of ideas about what could i do to make it work. I've been following these tutorials trying to make WOL work, but it just doesn't want to:

- https://www.maketecheasier.com/enable-wake-on-lan-ubuntu/

- https://www.techrepublic.com/videos/how-to-enable-wake-on-lan-in-ubuntu-server-18-04
- https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/8563-activar-wake-on-lan-ubuntu-server/
- https://www.golinuxcloud.com/wake-on-lan-ubuntu/

When running ethtool i get

```
   Supports Wake-on: pumbg
   Wake-on: g
```

Any idea about what could i be doing wrong? I've followed the tutorials line by line multiple times.